# Add another element to a jQuery selector after I add a variable to the mix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how I can add another element to a jQuery selector after I add a variable to the mix.

Here's what I have currently:

```
var className = $(this).attr('class');
$('.case-study-each-landing-container h3 span.' + className).css('color','#FCB709');
```

I'm needing to add an `a` after `+ className` to continue down the tree. I thought this would work, which didn't bring back any errors, but doesn't seem to work?

```
$('.case-study-each-landing-container h3 span.' + className + 'a').css('color','#FCB709');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
R

Comment: `$('.case-study-each-landing-container h3 span.' + className + ' a')` need a space

Comment: You're missing a space that would separate the selectors, at the moment you are just apending `a` onto your class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing a space before the a:

```
$('.case-study-each-landing-container h3 span.' + className + ' a').css('color','#FCB709');
```